# Sql Sum Multiplying Results

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sum, inner-join

I've trying to convert this same into a "Gross Profit" type report and am running into an issue.

```
select 
   CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), ih.invoice_date,110) as invoice_date, 
   oh.order_no, 
   bosr.salesrep_name, 
   bosr.salesrep_id,
   oh.location_id, 
   oh.taker, 
   oh.customer_id, 
   Replace(oh.ship2_name, ',', ' ') as Ship_to_name,
   bosr.supplier_id, 
   Replace(bosr.supplier_name, ',', ' ') as Supplier_name,
   Cast((dc.dealer_commission_amt_due) as DECIMAL (19,2)) as "Gross Profit"
from oe_hdr oh 
 inner join anspin_view_booked_orders_ship_to_rep bosr
   on oh.order_no = bosr.order_no
 inner join oe_line ol 
   on oh.order_no = ol.order_no
 inner join invoice_hdr ih 
   on oh.order_no = ih.order_no
 inner join dealer_commission dc 
   on ih.invoice_no = dc.invoice_no
where 
  ih.invoice_date >= '2014-07-01' and
  ih.invoice_date < '2014-08-01' and
  ol.qty_ordered > '0' and
  bosr.source_code_no <> '706' and
  bosr.source_code_no <> '709'
group by 
  CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), ih.invoice_date, 110),
  oh.order_no, 
  bosr.salesrep_name, 
  bosr.salesrep_id,
  oh.location_id, 
  oh.customer_id, 
  oh.taker, 
  oh.ship2_name,
  bosr.supplier_id, 
  bosr.supplier_name, 
  dc.dealer_commission_amt_due
order by invoice_date;
```

This worked great and the "Gross Profit" column is showing the correct values in the date range I want...now if I were to remove the "dc.dealer_commission_amt_due" from the group by, and then make this change:

```
 Cast(sum(dc.dealer_commission_amt_due) as DECIMAL (19,2)) as "Gross Profit"
```

I get amounts in SOME (Not all! Which is weird since some are correct) of the invoice numbers as 2-4+ times their original value.

Example Between the two:

```
invoice_date order_no salesrep_name salesrep_id location_id taker   customer_id Ship_to_name    supplier_id Supplier_name   Gross Profit
 07-10-2014   X         NAME          ID           60       NAME    X           Customer INC    123452      supplier INC.   4800.00
```

Non-Sum:

```
invoice_date order_no salesrep_name salesrep_id location_id taker   customer_id Ship_to_name    supplier_id Supplier_name   Gross Profit
 07-10-2014   X         NAME          ID           60       NAME    X           Customer INC    123452      supplier INC.   750.00
invoice_date order_no salesrep_name salesrep_id location_id taker   customer_id Ship_to_name    supplier_id Supplier_name   Gross Profit
 07-10-2014   X         NAME          ID           60       NAME    X           Customer INC    123452      supplier INC.   450.00
```

From what I've read this has to do with the joins...is this correct?

Comment: I`m guessing it`s because of different granularity,you have to get that sum in a subquery using group by and JOIN on that.

Comment: Your joins are produces an unexpected multiplication of rows.  Run the query with not aggregation for one of the invoices where the total is not correct.  You will see extra rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up having to pay for the software company to write a query since they have the "encyclopedia" on linking the different tables together.

I was able to get 50% there by getting rid of the multiplication on my own, but only 50% of the order types were showing up...I gave up and now have a working query that I can compare against.

Thanks for all your help and suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

These two queries are not the same:

```
SELECT Cast(( dc.dealer_commission_amt_due ) AS DECIMAL (19, 2)) AS  "Gross Profit" 
FROM  dealer_commission dc 
GROUP BY  dc.dealer_commission_amt_due 


SELECT Cast(( SUM(dc.dealer_commission_amt_due) ) AS DECIMAL (19, 2)) AS "Gross Profit" 
FROM  dealer_commission dc
```

Adding additional columns in your GROUP BY clause will return more rows in the result, but it should not effect the sum.  Removing a column in the GROUP BY will return less rows and again should not effect the sum.

The only part of the query that can effect the sum is which rows are matched.

Also, keep in mind the order of operations of a query:

```
FROM  
WHERE  
GROUP BY  
HAVING  
SELECT  
ORDER BY
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need an aggregation?

```
select 
   CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), ih.invoice_date,110) as invoice_date, 
   oh.order_no, 
   bosr.salesrep_name, 
   bosr.salesrep_id,
   oh.location_id, 
   oh.taker, 
   oh.customer_id, 
   Replace(oh.ship2_name, ',', ' ') as Ship_to_name,
   bosr.supplier_id, 
   Replace(bosr.supplier_name, ',', ' ') as Supplier_name,
   SUM(Cast((dc.dealer_commission_amt_due) as DECIMAL (19,2))) as "Gross Profit"  --<<AGGREGATION ADDED
from oe_hdr oh 
 inner join anspin_view_booked_orders_ship_to_rep bosr
   on oh.order_no = bosr.order_no
 inner join oe_line ol 
   on oh.order_no = ol.order_no
 inner join invoice_hdr ih 
   on oh.order_no = ih.order_no
 inner join dealer_commission dc 
   on ih.invoice_no = dc.invoice_no
where 
  ih.invoice_date >= '2014-07-01' and
  ih.invoice_date < '2014-08-01' and
  ol.qty_ordered > '0' and
  bosr.source_code_no <> '706' and
  bosr.source_code_no <> '709'
group by 
  CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), ih.invoice_date, 110),
  oh.order_no, 
  bosr.salesrep_name, 
  bosr.salesrep_id,
  oh.location_id, 
  oh.customer_id, 
  oh.taker, 
  oh.ship2_name,
  bosr.supplier_id, 
  bosr.supplier_name
order by invoice_date;
```

Comment: Same Result when I run this :(

Comment: you are saying with `SUM` this has one record at 4800 whereas if you do not use `SUM` there are two rows which between them add up to 1200 ?